# Iterating a json object and appending index to it

Tags: javascript, json

I want to append **index** to the end of json object which will begin at '1' and ONLY increment if 'seq' is 1 as illustrated in the example below.

**My current code is only iterating and +1 without checking for seq condition of '1'.**

> ```
> for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.myDataset.length; i++) {
>     $scope.myDataset[i - 1].index = i;
> }
> ```

**This is what I want. After appending index to it.**

```
$scope.myDataset = [
    {   
        seq:        '1',
        index: '1',
    },
    {
        seq:        '2',
        index: '1',
    },
    {
        seq:        '3',
        index: '1',
    },
    {
        seq:        '4',
        index: '1',
    },
    {
        seq:        '1',
        index: '2',
    },
    {
        seq:        '2',
        index: '2',
    },
    {
        seq:        '3',
        index: '2',
    },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try this:

```
var cnt = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myDataset.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.myDataset[i].seq === '1') cnt++;
    $scope.myDataset[i].index = cnt;
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'seq' of undefined... Why so? really puzzle

Comment: It only produces the correct result if the first object in the array has `seq` equal to `1`

Comment: You have `[i-1]` @Joal. Why would you initialize your loop to index `1` and do `i-1` to access the elements anyway

Comment: It should not be the case. Check if you copy/paste correctly and make sure your `$scope` exists. Which line throws TypeError?

Answer (score 0):

Use if statement to check if this seq value is 1 so index will be added to it or if not set index to 0.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.myDataset.length; i++)
if($scope.myDataset[i-1].seq==1){
$scope.myDataset[i - 1].index = i;
}
else{$scope.myDataset[i-1].index=0;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Sir!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `forEach` to loop on objects and conditionally set the `index` property:

```js
var $scope = {},
    i = 0;
$scope.myDataset = [{
    seq: '1'
  },
  {
    seq: '2'
  },
  {
    seq: '3'
  },
  {
    seq: '4'
  },
  {
    seq: '1'
  },
  {
    seq: '2'
  },
  {
    seq: '3'
  },
];
$scope.myDataset.forEach(function(elt) {
  elt.index = (elt.seq === '1') ? ++i : i;
});
console.log($scope.myDataset);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help sir!